# how to convert amount to text in openerp 7 in Accounting and Finance module?

Tags: odoo

```
cr.execute("""select sum(debit-credit) from account_move_line where id={0}',(account.id)""")
amount = cr.fetchall()
```

help me in problem:

NameError: global name 'cr' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like this line are under report .py file. So you don't have cr, uid, ids, context variable in your report.

In OpenERP, *self* refers the current object. So you may try this:

```
self.cr.execute("""select sum(debit-credit) from account_move_line where id={0}',(account.id)""")
amount = self.cr.fetchall()
```

Hope this will solve your problem.